# using getFragmentSupport Manager inside PreferenceFragment

Tags: java, android, preferences

I found this library that I want to use inside my PreferenceFragment extended class, my problem is that the getSupportFragmentManager can not be resolved.
My question is how do I show the fragment when it extends a PreferenceFragment

I tried changing to getFragmentManager but won't work

```
public class PreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

 final Preference currencyPreference = findPreference(getResources().getString(R.string.setting_category_currency_key));
        currencyPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(preference -> {
            //selectCurrencyDialog = new SelectCurrencyFragment();
            //selectCurrencyDialog.show(((SettingsActivity) getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager(), "SelectCurrency");

            CurrencyPicker picker = CurrencyPicker.newInstance("Select Currency");  // dialog title
            picker.setListener((name, code, symbol, flagDrawableResID) -> {
                // Implement your code here
            });
            picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "CURRENCY_PICKER");

            return false;
        });

}
```

The error is on this Line

> getSupportFragmentManager()

```
picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "CURRENCY_PICKER");
```

Answer (score 0):

use getChildFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: It won't work Error error: no suitable method found for show(android.app.FragmentManager,String)

Comment: @AnnaMurray fragment and Fragment manager package is mismatched . can you both imported packages as same?

Comment: I am using the PreferenceFragment

Comment: what's the package name of base fragment of PreferenceFragment?

Comment: it is based in PreferenceFragment

Answer (score 0):

In **Fragment** use -

```
picker.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "CURRENCY_PICKER");
```

In **Activity** use -

```
picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "CURRENCY_PICKER");
```

Comment: Use PreferenceFragmentCompat instead of PreferenceFragment then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried replacing `getSupportFragmentManager()` with `PreferencesFragment.this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`?

This works by returning the parent activity of your `PreferencesFragment` and obtaining it's fragment manager. You would want to use `PreferencesFragment.this.getActivity().getFragmentManager()` instead, if your parent activity extends an activity from the support library.